# Convert Excel Formula to IF/Else in PHP

Tags: php, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

An excel question (probably not the best place to ask)

I have an MS Excel formula that I am trying to 'convert' into PHP using IF/Else statements - is there any Excel gurus that could write the following line into pseudocode?

```
=IF(C10=0,IF(ABS(E2+C2)<0.51,"balanced",IF(ABS(E2+C2)<1.34,"slightly greater",IF(ABS(E2)<2.67,"slightly greater",IF(ABS(C2)>1.17,"slightly greater","significantly greater")))),IF(C10<1.18,"Low",IF(C10<2.68,IF(ABS(E2+C2)>0.51,IF(ABS(E2)>1.18,"High","Moderate"),"Moderate"),"High")))
```

Comment: `is there any Excel gurus that could write the following line into pseudocode?` So your question is, can somebody do this for me? Not on this site...

Comment: My bad - I had tried a number of things I'm just not familiar with Excel will have a whirl..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't change the conditions, assuming you know how to do that, but I converted the nesting for you

```
if(C10=0) {
    if(ABS(E2+C2)<0.51) {
        "balanced",
    } else {
        if(ABS(E2+C2)<1.34) {
            "slightly greater",
        } else {
            if(ABS(E2)<2.67) {
                "slightly greater",
            } else {
                if(ABS(C2)>1.17) {
                    "slightly greater",
                } else {
                    "significantly greater"
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    if(C10<1.18) {
        "Low"
    } else {
        if(C10<2.68) {
            if(ABS(E2+C2)>0.51) {
                if(ABS(E2)>1.18) {
                    "High"
                } else {
                    "Moderate"
                }
            } else {
                "Moderate"
            }
        } else {
            "High"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that Rob - will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Cheers @Rob - I used your pseudocode and slowly managed to work it out!! Many Thanks again problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

haven't tested it:

```
if($c10 == 0)
{
    if(( abs($e2+$c2) > 0.51) && ( abs($e2+$c2) < 1.34)){
        echo "slightly greater";
    }
    elseif( abs($e2+$c2) < 0.51) {
        echo "balanced";
    }
    elseif( abs($e2) < 2.67){
        echo "slightly greater";
    }
    elseif( abs($c2) < 1.17){
        echo "slightly greater";
    }
    else{
        echo "significantly greater";
    }
}
elseif($c10 < 1.18) {
    echo "Low";
}
elseif(($c10 < 2.68) && ($c10 > 1.18)){
    if( abs($e2+$c2) > 0.51){
        if(abs($e2) > 1.18{
            echo "High";
        }
        else{
            echo "Moderate";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Moderate";
    }
}
else{
    echo "High";
}
```

important bit to get logical operation right. i.e. if $c less than 2.68, but greater than 1.18 - do this.

Comment: much appreciated im sure this will help me

Comment: you wrote above that you are not familiar with Excel - maybe this will help you - IF operation in Excel works as => IF(Logical test (i.e. C10 < 1.18),(comma) here goes the code if the logical test is TRUE, (comma) here goes the code if the logical test is FALSE)

Comment: Thanks Elen that really helps - worked it out in the end with help from yourself & Rob. Thanks again